# unexpected endwhile effor in php

Tags: php, mysql

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE), expecting end of file in D:\xampp\htdocs\thelewala\includes\navigation.php on line 26

this is  code

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 0";
$pquery = $db->query($sql);
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">THELEWALAONLINE</a>

  <!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
<?php while($parent = mysqli_fatch_assoc($pquery)) ; ?>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">Shop</a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Men's</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sport's</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Women's</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kid's</a>
  </div>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: it's a silly little typo, well 2 actually,

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while($parent = mysqli_fatch_assoc($pquery)) :  ?>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data- 
toggle="dropdown">Shop</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Men's</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sport's</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Women's</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kid's</a>
</div>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

change `;` to `:` in while loop statement

Comment: thank you sir, now it is working after replacing ; to : and fatch to fetch.

Comment: Do switch the green tick when something better is posted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers